# Flutter Mapbox Navigation Problems with android 12 and 13

Tags: android, flutter, android-12, android-13, mapbox-navigation

I use flutter_mapbox_navigation to navigate in real map inside app. I use version 0.0.26. In iOS I have no problems and it works fine. In android 11 it works fine. In android 12 and 13 the app crash in the moment I open navigation view.

Could someone help me? I think it could be a case of permission missing or something else only required from android 12 version because in android 11 version it works fine.